why does `watch` skip every other line when --no-wrap in enabled and all the lines are short
If I run this command:
watch --no-wrap 'echo 0\\n1\\n2\\n3\\n4\\n5\\n6\\n7\\n8\\n9'

I get this output:
Every 2.0s: echo 0\\n1\\n2\\n3\\n4\\n5\\n6\\n7\\n8\\n9                                                           dave: Thu Apr 18 18:06:55 2024

0
2
4
6
8

Which seems very strange.  As the documentation in --help says the following:
-w, --no-wrap          turn off line wrapping

These are not long lines, and shouldn't require wrapping.  And even if they did, we should still see the beginning of each line...
For comparison, here is the output without the --no-wrap
Every 2.0s: echo 0\\n1\\n2\\n3\\n4\\n5\\n6\\n7\\n8\\n9                                                           dave: Thu Apr 18 18:10:32 2024

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Some relevant info about my setup:
% watch --version
watch from procps-ng 3.3.17
% echo $LINES $COLUMNS 
45 143


I have the same version on my system and it works. `Every 2.0s: echo 0\n1\n2\...  localhost.localdomain: Thu Apr 18 13:05:05 2024
0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9
`

Odd. My version of watch (from procps-ng 3.3.15) does not have a --no-wrap option and does not result in the \\ns being decoded to newlines.

watch 3.3.17 seems to skip lines if the output is <= $COLUMNS and --no-wrap is specified.

I reproduced it on my system with $COLUMNS == 180

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Easy to reproduce the problem when you add -e to the echo cmd.  Is your echo command and alias for echo -e?  run alias and see if it is

Not related to echo though

@Barmar I can delete this post if you want.  I sympathize with your position, however I think that shell scripting really blurs the line between using utilities and programming.  IMO, practically speaking, this is very relevant to shell scripting as you would almost certainly use this in a script, as I was.  Furthermore I am composing commands together which is inherently within the domain of scripting

@GoinOff It seems that watch is doing the \n conversion, not echo. When I run that command outside watch they show up literally.

@DaveButler There's overlap, but my general criteria is that it belongs over there if the problem is unrelated to the program's use in programming. Similarly, if you're having a problem using apt-get, it doesn't usually become on-topic here because the package you're trying to install is used for programming.

rebuild your version with this patch https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/commit/8a65a30#6d88a78
or update to a newer version than that
